# mmap on iOS returns sometimes 0xffffffff

Tags: ios, c, mmap

I try to use mmap on iOS devices with the following code

```
struct stat s;
    int status;
    size_t size;
    int fd;

    fd = open ([dataFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], O_RDONLY);
    fcntl( fd, F_NOCACHE );
    status = fstat (fd, & s);
    if (status < 0)
    {
        // error handling
    }
    size = s.st_size;
    FuncFileLog(@"%@", @"before read");
    off_t offset = 0;
    char* data = (char *) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset);

    char *pch;
    int lastPosInString = 0;

    pch=strchr(data,'\n');

long lineCounter = 0;

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        size_t lineLength = 0;

        int posInString = pch - data + 1;
        lineLength = posInString - lastPosInString;

        char *out = calloc(lineLength, sizeof(char));

        memcpy(out, data + lastPosInString, lineLength);
        out[lineLength - 1] = '\0';

        if (lineCounter > 0)
        {
           // do something
        }

        lastPosInString = posInString;
        pch=strchr(pch+1,'\n');

        lineCounter = lineCounter + 1;
    }

    munmap((void *)data, size);
    close(fd);
```

It works but sometimes for no reason when I read a file about 3.5 mb I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS because my data pointer from mmap is `0xffffffff`which is an error I think.
ANd it seems only to happen in simulator.

I get
`errno:12 Cannot allocate memory`
currently only in simulator with
guard malloc, guard edges, scribble and zombies on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading the man page for `mmap` (open the Terminal.app and type `man mmap`)

```
RETURN VALUES
     Upon successful completion, mmap() returns a pointer to the mapped region.  
     Otherwise, a value of MAP_FAILED is returned and errno is set to indicate 
     the error.
```

There is also a section that describe the `errno`'s that might be set too.

Comment: thanks, now I see its errno:12 Cannot allocate memory 
It happens at the moment only when I run in simulator with guard malloc and scribble